# Measures and Outer Measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I've a "little" doubt. 
From *Carathéodory-Hahn Extension Theorem*, we know that, starting from a measure space $\ (X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$, we are always able to obtain an outer measure $\ \mu ^* $. Then we can see $\ \mu ^*$ as an extension of $\mu $ defined on all $\ \mathcal{P}(X)$.

The question is: is it possible to do the converse? I.e., is every outer measure $\mu:\mathcal{P}(X)\to [0,+\infty]$ an extension of a certain measure defined on some sigma $\ \mathcal{M}\subseteq X$?

Comment: We take under $\cal{M}$ the following class:$\{X,\emptyset\}$. Then the $\mu$ will be an extension of the measure $\lambda$ for which $\lambda(X)=\mu(X)$ and $\lambda(\emptyset)=0$. In your question, in my sense, must be added the following sentence:"such that $\mu$ is an outer measure generated by this measure?"

Comment: And does it hold the following equality: $\ \mu(E)=$inf$\  \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\lambda(A_i): .....\right\} $ for every $\ E\subseteq X$?